# javascript - Getting "Undefined" simple function with loop

Tags: javascript, jscript

So i can't seem to figure this out...  The code essentially works, but i get an "undefined" prior to the function running..

```
var navRender = function indexNav(x,y) {

    var mainNav = ["\/", "Inicio","\/abogados-criminales-los-angeles.html", "Defensa Criminal", 
    "\/delitos-de-drogas-abogados.html", "Delitos de Drogas", 
    "\/area-de-practica-abogados.html", "Areas de Practica",
    "\/abogados-friendman-los-angeles.html", "Abogados Friedman",
    "\/contactenos.html", "Contactenos"];

    for (i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        document.write("<li class=\"pure-menu-item pure-u-1-3\"><a class=\"pure-menu-link href=\"",mainNav[i]);
        i++;
        document.write("\">", mainNav[i] , "<\/a><\/li>");
    };
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = navRender(0,5);

</script>
```

Also,  i don't know why my "forward slashes are not working either.. i'm escaping with like " /".. but they still get omitted..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *but i get an "undefined" prior to the function running* — Where?

Comment: on the browser i get:

`code` <ul class="pure-menu-list" id="demo">undefined</ul>

Comment: Where on the browser? In the Console of the developer tools? In the HTML document? How could that be **before** the function runs?

Comment: checks if y too big for array if undefined is element that you want put in html.

Comment: So, your function didn't return anything, it just write on the *document* all the html. So when you assign the return value from the function execution on your "demo" element, you got your undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right way of doing it.

```js
var navRender = function indexNav(x, y) {

  var mainNav = ["\/", "Inicio", "\/abogados-criminales-los-angeles.html", "Defensa Criminal", "\/delitos-de-drogas-abogados.html", "Delitos de Drogas", "\/area-de-practica-abogados.html", "Areas de Practica", "\/abogados-friendman-los-angeles.html", "Abogados Friedman", "\/contactenos.html", "Contactenos"];

  var html = "";

  for (i = x; i <= y; i = i + 2) {
    html = html + "<li class='pure-menu-item pure-u-1-3'><a class='pure-menu-link' href='" + mainNav[i] + "'>" + mainNav[i + 1] + "</a></li>";
  };

  return html;
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = navRender(0, 5);
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! thats it!

Comment: How come the forward slashes works correctly on your answer and for the others, it doesnt?  i get what you on the script.. but i don't see any changes on the  forward slash escapes

Comment: @JhonatanVillena : I have reformatted the syntax. Check my answer for how to do it. You can use a single quote(`'`) instead of escaping a double quote( i.e. `\"`).

Answer (score 0):

=> Remove **i++** from for loop.Because it is also plus in for loop.

```js
var navRender = function indexNav(x,y) {

     var mainNav = ["\/", "Inicio","\/abogados-criminales-los-angeles.html", "Defensa Criminal", 
     "\/delitos-de-drogas-abogados.html", "Delitos de Drogas", 
     "\/area-de-practica-abogados.html", "Areas de Practica",
     "\/abogados-friendman-los-angeles.html", "Abogados Friedman",
     "\/contactenos.html", "Contactenos"];

  for (i = x; i <= y; i++) 
   {
      document.write("<li class=\"pure-menu-item pure-u-1-3\"><a class=\"pure-menu-link href=\"",mainNav[i]);
      document.write("\">", mainNav[i] , "<\/a><\/li>");
   };
 };
 navRender(0,5);
```

Comment: i need the second i++  since my array has the link and text.. so  and they are pair by two.. so for me to run the second loop i need to advance two positions..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var navRender = function indexNav(x,y) {

     var mainNav = ["\/", "Inicio", "\/abogados-criminales-los-angeles.html", "Defensa Criminal", "\/delitos-de-drogas-abogados.html", "Delitos de Drogas", "\/area-de-practica-abogados.html", "Areas de Practica", "\/abogados-friendman-los-angeles.html", "Abogados Friedman", "\/contactenos.html", "Contactenos"];
  
  var result = '';
  for (var i = x; i <= y; i = i + 2) {
    result += '<li class="pure-menu-item pure-u-1-3\">'
    result += '<a class="pure-menu-link" href="' + mainNav[i] + '">' + mainNav[i + 1];
    result += '</a>';
    result += '</li>';
  }

  return result;
 };
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = navRender(0,5);
```

```html
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```